House has no plumbing vent, how do I fix it myself?
My house is over a 100 years old, so it doesn't have any plumbing vents. This is everything that happens:

My toilet randomly overflows, usually in the middle of the night,or when I'm not home for a few days.

Gurgling sounds in my toilet, bathroom sink and bathtub drains.

Low water pressure/flow from faucets, sometimes standing water in the sinks and bathtub.

Slow drainage of water in the sink, bathtub. Smelling sewage, rotten eggs, or dead frogs.


Please, tell me how to fix my house.

A simple plumbing vent is just an extension pipe of the main drain line through the roof.  If the plumbing is as old as the house, most of the pipes(drain and supply) will be at or very near end of life.  Most pipe replacement can be DIY.  More information about your plumbing edited into the question will help.

Welcome to DIY.SE! There seem to be lots of YouTube videos on adding vents to existing plumbing. Probably every step is shown in a video somewhere, so this will put your project within your grasp, and you can always come and ask questions about something the videos don't explain well. FWIW slow water from faucets won't be fixed by a drain plumbing vent; try asking a new question about that with a description of your water supply.

You haven't told us anything about your plumbing or the layout of your home. How are we supposed to help? Please do some research on your own and come back with a more specific question, and provide enough information for us to help. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Not sure of your skill set so I will just say what I would do as a DIYer.
Get a 50ft drain auger from your home store, rent or buy, and run it down each drain in the house and from any cutout to the street to clear out junk that has accumulated over the past number of years and will hopefully improve the draining. Then install some air admittance valves under your sink cabinets into the drains to help with the venting. This could help with the toilet operation too and will also reduce the suction that's emptying the traps and causing the foul oders. The low water pressure is probably caused by rusting in the old galvanized pipes or a bad water pressure regulator. You can remove any aerators on your faucets and clean them out from any rust. The water company could probably check the regulator. If the pipes interior rusting is the major reason for the slow water, they will have to be replaced. This is easier with all the flexible tubing out there but can still really be a big, time consuming job.

I might add, if the house has a septic tank, it may need a pump-out, too.

@Triplefault   Good point, especially with the age of the house.
